Next.js 14 - require crypto error with mysql2 in turbo mode
For the past few days, I've been trying to get turbo mode working in Next.js 14 with MySQL2. Despite using every available resource to solve the issue, I'm still stuck with the error. My large project takes 20 seconds to compile every time I change.
I am getting following crypto console error
./node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:27:16
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'
  25 | */
  26 |
> 27 | const crypto = require('crypto');
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  28 |
  29 | function sha1(msg, msg1, msg2) {
  30 |   const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');

Here is what I did ...

Installed crypto, crypto-browserify and stream-browserify

Added the following webpack related settings in next.config file


/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      }
      return config;
    },
    webpack: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        },
      }
    }
  };
  
  module.exports = nextConfig;


Added the following entries in package.json

"browser": {
    "tls": false,
    "net": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false
  }

